# A Jtable implementation

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to implement a JTable which will only be edited and updated programatically. I dont want user interaction enabled.

Firstly the input will be from an array of string elements(after filling the array from a String split).

I then want to set the fields with the array data.

How are the column names stored as Final or whatever for the table life?

Do I need to implement a TableModel if I dont want interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably read through the Java documentation for [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Things you seem interested in:

[`isCellEditable()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) - Have it return `false` means the user can not edit any cells.
[`getColumnName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnName%28int%29) - Look up the name in an array or list of strings.

Comment: +1, the key is overriding isCellEditable so the user can't change the data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding editability: use JXTable - it supports layered programatic configuration control. Specifically,

- supports per-column and per-table narrowing (that is, to read-only)
- respects the cell editable property always (that is table.setValueAt does nothing if the cell is not editable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the model will be useful but not necessary (also just a `DefaultTableModel`).

Actually you could just fill the JTable with static data using the right constructor:

```
public JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)
```

but you won't have any control over the data inside the table.

The model is not used just to provide interaction with editing capabilities but to provide a data source for the table either to read either to write, that's why it's always good to have one.

Comment: Ok nice. I will need a data source so I will implement a model. So just to get the steps clear. create a Jtable, create the model which holds the data source. How are these connected? Also I have methods to search the [][] for a name and return the index of the array. Which I then fill this array with values at its index. Where should these method be defined? Outside of the model or? Thanks